# Why would PowerShell not be able to update its own directory?

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions

Why would PowerShell not have access to its own help directory?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Update-Help
Update-Help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Operation.Validation' with UI culture(s) {en-US} : Access to the path 'C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Operation.Validation\1.0.1\en-US' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Help
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Update-Help], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnknownErrorId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateHelpCommand
```

This is the Windows 10 installed PowerShell. There is no `en-US` directory under

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Operation.Validation\1.0.1\
```

There are several other `en-US` directories.

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell>dir en-us /s /b /a:d
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PackageManagement\1.0.0.1\en-US
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.3.5\en-US
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Pester\3.4.0\en-US
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\en-US
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadline\1.1\en-US
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadline\1.2\en-US
```

Comment: Because a process by default has the lowest permissions possible unless they are elevated by an Administrator

Comment: PowerShell was started with "Run as Administrator."

Comment: Have a look at the permissions on the target folder. Even Administrators can not have permissions to a file/folder.

Comment: Access Denied? Have you made sure it's set correctly in your Path? Open terminal type Path. Or even type Path > path.txt so you can read it easier in notepad. Make sure the path is correct. I had a problem with mine in the past is the only reason I mention it.

Comment: Also my path for PowerShell is: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; Did you drop yours in as self install or install it? And on my pc this folder is empty: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules (totally empty on mine). It seems I changed something in the past, but so long ago I don't remember.

Comment: The PowerShell path is there. It is only the `en-US` directory that is missing. I would have thought that Microsoft would keep up with such a directory.

Comment: The `en-US` folder won’t exist until you run `Update-Help`, so that’s normal. You say you started PS as Admin, does the title bar read “Administrator: Windows PowerShell”? Did you install any security software or old(-ish) software? The permissions are supposed to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amApi.png).

Comment: My SYSTEM and Administrators do not have the same permission settings as yours. However, when I try to change the settings, everything is grayed out. I cannot change the permission settings. How can I overcome that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PowerShell still encounters an access-denied error when running as administrator, then Administrators does not have sufficient access to the folder in question.

Open the properties window on the lowest-level directory that exists on the path you were given. Go to the Security tab and click Advanced. If everything is grayed out, take ownership using the Change link at the top, then OK the advanced security settings dialog, then reopen it. You will now be able to edit its access control list.

The correct permissions for `1.0.1` are:

- *Full control* on *This folder and subfolders* to TrustedInstaller
- All the basic permissions except *Full control* on *This folder only* to SYSTEM
- *Full control* on *Subfolders and files only* to SYSTEM
- The previous two again, but for Administrators - this is the key
- *Read & execute*, *List folder contents*, and *Read* on *This folder, subfolders, and files* to Users
- The one previous again, but for ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES and also ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES
- *Full control* on *Subfolders and files only* to CREATOR OWNER

Once you're done, it should look like this:

[image: the final advanced security settings]

In general, if permissions on an item look wrong, try copying them over from a working machine.

Once that's done, elevated PowerShell will be able to create the appropriate files and folders.

Comment: Many thanks, Ben N. It gives the impression that it is working now. I still do not know how the machine got into this state. I have only run Microsoft installs and Windows Update to set up PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue. For me, the culture subfolder (en-US) did not exist. I manually created the en-US subfolder and copied all of the folders and file into the en-US folder that were in the 1.0.1 folder (some were locked). After this, Update-Help worked.

It seems like something changed to want a culture, but this module did not conform to that standard. The date of the files and folders in this module is 3/18/2017, and the op posted the question on 4/18/2017.